# very very low validation accuracy and very high training accuracy python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm training a deep learning model and get a very low accuracy. I used L2 regularization to stop overfitting and to have high accuracy but it didn't solve the problem. what would be the cause of this very low accuracy and how can I stop it ?

The model accuracy is almost perfect (>90%) whereas the validation accuracy is very low (<51%) (shown bellow)

```
Epoch 1/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 1.6510 - accuracy: 0.5125 - val_loss: 1.6108 - val_accuracy: 0.4706
Epoch 2/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 1.1733 - accuracy: 0.7009 - val_loss: 1.5660 - val_accuracy: 0.4971
Epoch 3/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.9169 - accuracy: 0.8147 - val_loss: 1.6223 - val_accuracy: 0.4948
Epoch 4/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.7820 - accuracy: 0.8551 - val_loss: 1.7773 - val_accuracy: 0.4683
Epoch 5/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.6539 - accuracy: 0.8989 - val_loss: 1.7968 - val_accuracy: 0.4937
Epoch 6/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.5691 - accuracy: 0.9204 - val_loss: 1.8743 - val_accuracy: 0.4844
Epoch 7/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.5090 - accuracy: 0.9327 - val_loss: 1.9348 - val_accuracy: 0.5029
Epoch 8/15
2601/2601 - 40s - loss: 0.4465 - accuracy: 0.9500 - val_loss: 1.9566 - val_accuracy: 0.4787
Epoch 9/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.3931 - accuracy: 0.9596 - val_loss: 2.0824 - val_accuracy: 0.4764
Epoch 10/15
2601/2601 - 41s - loss: 0.3786 - accuracy: 0.9596 - val_loss: 2.1185 - val_accuracy: 0.4925
Epoch 11/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.3471 - accuracy: 0.9604 - val_loss: 2.1972 - val_accuracy: 0.4879
Epoch 12/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.3169 - accuracy: 0.9669 - val_loss: 2.1091 - val_accuracy: 0.4948
Epoch 13/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.3018 - accuracy: 0.9685 - val_loss: 2.2073 - val_accuracy: 0.5006
Epoch 14/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.2629 - accuracy: 0.9746 - val_loss: 2.2086 - val_accuracy: 0.4971
Epoch 15/15
2601/2601 - 38s - loss: 0.2700 - accuracy: 0.9650 - val_loss: 2.2178 - val_accuracy: 0.4879
```

I tried to increase the number of epoch, and it only increases the model accuracy and lowers the validation accuracy.

Any advice on how to overcome this issue?

**My code:**

```
def createModel():
    input_shape=(11, 3840,1)
    model = Sequential()
    #C1
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), strides=( 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=( 2, 2),  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #C2
    model.add(Conv2D(32, ( 3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same',  activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    
     #C3
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=( 1,1), padding='same',  activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))  
  
    opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy']) 
    return model
```

```
def getFilesPathWithoutSeizure(indexSeizure, indexPat):
    filesPath=[]
    print(indexSeizure)
    print(indexPat)
    for i in range(0, nSeizure):
        if(i==indexSeizure):
            filesPath.extend(interictalSpectograms[i])
            filesPath.extend(preictalSpectograms[i])
    shuffle(filesPath)
    return filesPath

def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
            x = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(x, axis=0), axis = 0)
            x = x.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
            if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            yield(x,y)
filesPath=getFilesPathWithoutSeizure(i, indexPat)
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75),#It take the first 75%
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75), #It take the last 25%
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))),
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
                                verbose=2,class_weight = {0:1, 1:1},
                                epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: is the `shuffle()` method in your `getFilesPathWithoutSeizure()` function as user defined function or are you importing it from some module?

Comment: @mb0850 yes I importing it by using `from random import shuffle`

Comment: if `filesPath` contains the all the filenames of your data, then it seems that shuffling is _not_ your problem. What about the size of your training dataset? If the number of training images are low then your model will automatically overfit.

Comment: @mb0850 I have 3467 numpy file in `filesPath` . I take 75% for training and 25% for validation.

Comment: @mb0850 what do you think ?? what causes this overfitting ??

Comment: You can try [Data Augmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation) for your images. Without looking more into your dataset, it would not be possible to understand the nuanced characteristics of the images. From the shape it seems to be quite weird `(11, 3840, 1)`

Comment: @mb0850 why `(11,3840,1)` weird ?? , why I should try data augmentation ??

Comment: This kind of questions are off-topic, overfitting is not a programming problem, you need to use regularization

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I already used regularization but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have implemented shuffling in the function `getFilesPathWithoutSeizure()`, though you could verify whether the shuffling is actually working or not by printing out the filenames multiple times.

`filesPath=getFilesPathWithoutSeizure(i, indexPat)` - is the `i` getting updated?

As per your code `if(i==indexSeizure):` in the method `getFilesPathWithoutSeizure`, only 1 file would return when indexSeizure is equal to the counter (`i` of the `for` loop)

If you are not changing `i` argument being passed during the function call, it could mean that only 1 file is being returned to the `filePath` variable and your whole training is done on 1 input data instead of the 75% of 3467 files.

--

After confirming that shuffling works and that your function call is inserting all the data in your `filePath` variable, it still doesn't solve your problem, then try the following:

Data Augmentation could help solve over-fitting by increasing the diversity of your dataset by applying random but realistic transformations such as image rotation, shearing, hortizontal & vertical flips, zooming, de-centering etc.

But more importantly you would need to manually look into your data and understand the similarity in your training data.

Another option would be to just get more and diverse data to train on.

Comment: I have confirmed that shuffling works. I don't update `i` but I set `indexSeizure` and `nSeizure` equal  zero having same value of `i` so all files returned to `filesPath` . Also I confirmed that all the data files returned to `filesPath` by printing `filesPath`  and the shape of `filesPath` is (3467,) .
Now I will try using Data Augmentation .

Answer (score 2):

Your model is overfitting and not generalizing properly. If your training set is completely different to your validation set (you are splitting 75% and 25% but the 75% could be completely different to the 25% ), your model will have a hard time generalizing.

Shuffle your data before you split into training and validation. That should improve your results.

Comment: how to shuffle data before splitting ?? I already shuffled my data in `model.fit_generator` by  `shuffle=True`

Comment: The argument `shuffle=True` in `fit_generator()` method is being ignored since the input_data is a generator.

Comment: I am guessing you are using a user-defined method called `generate_arrays_for_training()`. You would have to do some changes in this methods and add a shuffle component. You can refer to the [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) for more info

Comment: @mb0850 very well I understood. You mean that `shuffle=True` didn't work with `fit_generator` . I use shuffle in this function `getFilesPathWithoutSeizure` and pass `filesPath`  to  `generate_arrays_for_training()` . please check my code